# Compressing json for servlet response - correct way to do it?

Tags: java, json, servlets, gzip

So I have two questions:

1.) Sending byte[] as a servlet response.

2.) Correct way to send compressed json as a servlet response.

------ 1. Sending byte[] as a servlet response.-------

I have a java servlet that responds with a json string. This was working fine until the data grew and I had to use Gzip compression which compresses String to byte array (byte[]).

My question is how do I transfer that byte[] to client from this servlet. With json I just did this:

```
protected void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();) {
        out.write(jsonResponse); <---- THIS
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

But with byte[] it cannot be done so what would be the correct way?

---------- 2. Correct way to send compressed json as a servlet response.-------

Is this even the right idea? Compressin json response to byte[]?

My client at the moment is Android which can decompress this byte[] back to json, but mybe there are some things I just don't see coming with this approach?

Comment: Your servlet server can probably be configured to manage compression itself (and properly negotiate it with the browser). *This* is the right way.

Comment: Wow, this was quick answer :) I am new to server configuration, how would I go about doing this? I am using tomcat. Thanks

Comment: Search "tomcat 8 gzip compression"